# losing form fields - using jquery dialog modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a form. Within this form I am using a modal dialog, showed by a button click. The dialog contains a div including some input fields of the same form. Its contents are never transmitted to the server (method POST), so I started to debug a little bit...

1. When I don't open the dialog, the fields are available (server side)
2. When I open the dialog and type some values into the fields, the fields are no longer transmitted (not available)
3. If I don't hide (display: none) the div  - the field are visible when the form is loaded - and I fill it out without using the modal dialog , there are transmitted.

-> Why does the dialog "remove" the fields from my form???

Thank you for any input!
Urs

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="opener">other, please click here</button>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="type in the new elements:" style="display: none">
<p>country:<input type="text" class="small" id="othercountry" name="othercountry" value=""  </p>
<p>ccode:<input type="text" class="small" id="othercountryCode" name="othercountryCode" value=""></p></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
       height: 140,
       modal: true
    });
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).bind('dialogclose', function(event) 
      { do some other things, not relevant for the form }
    );
});
</script>
```

jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: There is nothing in the limited javascript and html you've posted that could be causing a problem - from what I can tell. You might need to provide your entire form markup and dialog javascript.

Answer (score 1):

By default, jQuery appends the dialog to the body, so you might have to move it back inside your form.  This can be done like this:

```
$('#dialog-modal').parent().appendTo($('form:first'))
```

See [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5762) for bug ticket

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for modal dialogs as the dialog itself then becomes ghosted out and you can't click into any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Never see your form tag, pure guess the form tag must be found inside the modal div.

```
<div id="dialog-modal" title="type in the new elements:" style="display: none">
    <form>
        <p>country:<input type="text" class="small" id="othercountry" name="othercountry" value=""  </p>
        <p>ccode:<input type="text" class="small" id="othercountryCode" name="othercountryCode" value=""></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and nothing i found actually worked.  As stated by others previously, the jquery dialog is moved from within the markup and appended to the body tag.  This is why it worked when you didnt open the dialog.  once opened the dialog is moved up to the body tag and outside the form tag.  I fixed this by putting a form tag within the dialog so no matter where it is it will always have a form to submit to the server.  Typically you have a div tag containing the dialog markup that is hidden and shown when necessary.  Just put a form tag within this div but outside all your input tags so they are all submitted when your button is clicked.  You can have multiple form tags but you cannot nest them so you should put all your jquery dialogs directly under the body tag but outside any other form tag so they dont conflict if the dialog is not shown yet.